# override handler level through logger.log

Tags: java, handler, java.util.logging

Is there a way to Override the Handler's level through logger Object.

Eg:

```
FileHandler logFile = new FileHandler("DefaultLogger.log");
logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

should set the fileHandler's level to fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Logger::getHandlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getHandlers()) method to acquire all of the install handlers for the given logger.  For example:

```
private static void setHandlersLevel(Logger logger, Level lvl) {
    for (Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
       h.setLevel(lvl);
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you want to find all handler on all loggers you can use the following:

```
private static void setAllHandlersLevel(Level lvl) {
    LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
    synchronized (lm) {
        Enumeration<String> e = lm.getLoggerNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Logger l = lm.getLogger(e.nextElement());
            if (l != null) {
                for (Handler h : l.getHandlers()) {
                    h.setLevel(lvl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```